# Android NullPointerException on findViewById()

Tags: java, android

I am starting an activity and trying to get a view (in this case a VideoView) via `findViewById();`
In most cases this works just fine, but sometimes it throws a NullPointerException, when I am trying to access the view I tried to find earlier.

This is the Activity I am in:

```
public class Video extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        VideoView videoView = this.findViewById(R.id.VideoViewVideo);
        videoView.setVideoURI(someURI);
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

The Exception is thrown in the line `videoView.setVideoURI(someURI);`and looks like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Video}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2678)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.VideoView.setVideoUri(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at Video.onCreate(Video.java:29)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6687)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)
```

The Layout file of the activity looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="Video">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoViewVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I assume there is something wrong in the way I am trying to get the view, but I don't know for sure.

It would be highly appreciated if someone could help me.

Comment: Perhaps you have configuration-specific layout folders and more than one activity_video.xml layout file? If so, make sure they all have a VideoView with the expected id.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the issue. I don't have any other files named activity_video.xml.

Comment: ... and no other `VideoView` with `android:id="@+id/VideoViewVideo"`?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that you have some stale build artifacts. Try doing a clean build.

Comment: Yep, I just checked that.
When I Ctrl+LeftClick on `VideoViewVideo` in the statement `findViewById()` Android Studio even points me to the correct view in the correct layout file.

Comment: `VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoViewVideo);`

Comment: @TedHopp the clean build fixed it. Is there something I did wrong, or is this just a common Gradle/AndroidStudio Problem?

Comment: This occasionally happens. As to whether you did anything wrong, I doubt it. Perhaps it's possible that you edited the source code while a Gradle build was in progress and the build got out of sync with itself.

Comment: I think something in your videoURL. can you please check it is correct or not? or you can just use butterknife for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move this code

```
VideoView videoView = this.findViewById(R.id.VideoViewVideo);
videoView.setVideoURI(someURI);
videoView.start();
```

to

```
@Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

  VideoView videoView = this.findViewById(R.id.VideoViewVideo);
  videoView.setVideoURI(someURI);
  videoView.start();

}
```

Sometimes if you want to make a view, you have to define it in onViewCreated instead of onCreate.

Let me know if it works

Answer (score -2):

Why You are writing
`VideoView videoView = this.findViewById(R.id.VideoViewVideo);` 
instead of the above your can write

`VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoViewVideo);`

Comment: Literally no difference

Comment: Ok then here i can see VideoView is a custom view check if it's initializing from javacode

Comment: It's not a custom view. The xml is given in the question. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html